# Using PHP to add multiple rows to MySQL with form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have been searching the web for days and I just can't figure this out.

I'm trying to insert form data into multiple rows in my MySQL database, but it doesn't work as I want it to. Is there anyone that can help me?

What I wanna do is to send a form to two separate tables. I want some info to go to a table called Dishes and other information into a table called Ingredients. The content that's being sent to the Dishes table is working as it should, it's the Ingredients table that doesn't take in the array of ingredients. I want the ingredients on multiple rows, depending on how many you enter.

As of now the Ingredient table is creating multiple rows in the table for every entry, but it doesn't input any data into the rows...

This is my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="insertrecipe.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="name_of_dish_heading">Name of dish</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="dish_name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="table_text">Short description:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><textarea name="dish_short_description" rows="3" cols="45"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="table_text">Ingredient:</td>
            <td class="table_text">Amount:</td>
            <td class="table_text">Type:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="ingredient[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ingred_amount[]" size="5"></td>
            <td>
                <select name="ingred_amount_type[]">
                   <option name="Milliliter" value="Milliliter">Milliliter (ML)</option>
                   <option name="Centiliter" value="Centiliter">Centiliter (CL)</option>
                   <option name="Deciliter" value="Deciliter">Deciliter (DL)</option>
                   <option name="Liter" value="Liter">Liter (L)</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="table_text">Ingredient:</td>
            <td class="table_text">Amount:</td>
            <td class="table_text">Type:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="ingredient[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ingred_amount[]" size="5"></td>
            <td>
                <select name="ingred_amount_type[]">
                   <option name="Milliliter" value="Milliliter">Milliliter (ML)</option>
                   <option name="Centiliter" value="Centiliter">Centiliter (CL)</option>
                   <option name="Deciliter" value="Deciliter">Deciliter (DL)</option>
                   <option name="Liter" value="Liter">Liter (L)</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add recipe">
</form>
```

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

// Connect to the database
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$dish_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['dish_name']);
$dish_short_description = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['dish_short_description']);

$sql1="INSERT INTO dishes (dish_name, dish_short_description)
VALUES ('$dish_name', '$dish_short_description')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1)) {
die('[Error: '.__LINE__.']: '.mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
echo "Added to the database.<br /><br />";
}

foreach($_POST['ingredient'] as $row=>$ingred) {
$ingredient = mysqli_real_escape_string($ingred); 
$ingred_amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['ingred_amount'][$row]);
$ingred_amount_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['ingred_amount_type'][$row]);

$query = "INSERT INTO ingredients (ingredient, ingred_amount, ingred_amount_type) VALUES ('$ingredient', '$ingred_amount', '$ingred_amount_type')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$query)) {
die('[Error: '.__LINE__.']: '.mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
echo "Added to the database.";
}
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Would greatly appreciate any help with this!

Comment: no errors? turn on error reporting to find out, and where is the foreign key of each ingredient which belongs to that dish

Comment: are you able to debug the value of 2nd query, if so is it as you expected?

Comment: Try `echo $query;` for the ingredients query and let as know of the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `$conn` when you are setting the value.

`mysqli_real_escape_string ();` require two parameter. one is connection

First one `$connection` and second is `string` which you want to escape.

Thats why you are not able to insert any thing. Even though your query is fine.

**Try this code when you are setting the value.**

```
$ingredient = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$ingred); //added $con in every line
$ingred_amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['ingred_amount'][$row]);
$ingred_amount_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['ingred_amount_type'][$row]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Because ingredient is array so first you need to count how many entry.


<?php

$dish_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['dish_name']);
$dish_short_description = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['dish_short_description']);

$sql1="INSERT INTO dishes (dish_name, dish_short_description)
VALUES ('$dish_name', '$dish_short_description')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1)) {
die('[Error: '.__LINE__.']: '.mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
echo "Added to the database.<br /><br />";
}

$no_of_entrys = count($_POST['ingredient']);

for ($i=0; $i < $no_of_entrys; $i++) { 
    $ingredient = mysqli_real_escape_string($ingred); 
    $ingred_amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['ingred_amount'][$row]);
    $ingred_amount_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['ingred_amount_type'][$row]);

    $query = "INSERT INTO ingredients (ingredient, ingred_amount, ingred_amount_type) VALUES    ('$ingredient', '$ingred_amount', '$ingred_amount_type')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$query)) {
    die('[Error: '.__LINE__.']: '.mysqli_error($con));
    }
    else {
    echo "Added to the database.";
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```